# How to upload a file - NO image - and comment it at the same time to Slack via SlackAPI using c#

Tags: c#, slack-api

I can upload images to Slack via my SlackAPI and I can upload files and I can upload images with comments - but I can not do this with files that are no images.
I'm sure it's a problem with my message-structure - have a look: All this is done via HttpClient!

This is my working fileUpload-method:

```
    public MultipartFormDataContent SendFileToChannel()
    {
        var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var fileContent = new StreamContent(GetFile.ReadFile());
        requestContent.Add(new StringContent(token), "token");
        requestContent.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(GetFile.path));

        return requestContent;
    }
```

there is no 'channel' in this method because I don't want to publish it yet.
Then I set "public_url_shared": true and get the public URL(with another method). 
In the response evreything seems to be okay, shared is set to true and I get a permalink_public-value which I pass on to post a message containing this file but...

Now I should be able to post a message while using the permalink_url I get from the second method. And this works with images. But it doesn't work with files.
I allways get the error response "no_file_data". 
Here is my method for this:

```
    public MultipartFormDataContent SendMessageWithFile(SlackFileResponse resp)
    {
        var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();            
        requestContent.Add(new StringContent(token), "token");            
        requestContent.Add(new StringContent(channel), "channel");
        requestContent.Add(new StringContent(text), "text");
        requestContent.Add(new StringContent("[{ \"fallback\":\"Anhang\", \"text\":\"\", \"\":\"" + resp.permalink_public + "\"}]"), "attachments");

        return requestContent;
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Because via the RTM-Slack one can easily just drag&drop a file in there and add a message to it. So it has to be possible via the SlackAPI ,too. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why this approach does not work:

Slack threats images differently from other files. Images are the **only** type of file that you can include in a message attachment via URL. For that we have the properties `image_url` (and `thumb_url`) for attachments.

Check out [this page](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments) for a list of all available attachment properties.

If you want to post any other file in a Slack channel and be able to comment it you need to upload it via `files.upload` and **share it immediately**. That is important, because it is currently not possible via the official API to share a previously uploaded file in a channel at a later point.

To include a comment with your file upload just set the `initial_comment` property in your API call.

Example:

```
var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new StreamContent(GetFile.ReadFile());
requestContent.Add(new StringContent(token), "token");
requestContent.Add(new StringContent("my_channel"), "channels");
requestContent.Add(new StringContent("Check out this amazing new file"), "initial_comment");
requestContent.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(GetFile.path));
```

Comment: I like to add that there is an undocumented API method called [files.share](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/files.share.md) that allows you to share uploaded files later. However, I would not recommend you to use it, since they require a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) to work and are officially not supported.

Comment: Hey, I'm sure I tried that already. When I use the files.upload I can not add any comment to it for the upload... I added the neccesary parameter(text) but it doesn't show when I use that method. And when I use chat.postMessage I obviously can not add a file...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can actually include a comment with the upload, but you need to provide the correct parameter to the API.

Comment: I will add the info you need to my answer. But if I may: I would recommend you to start working more closely with the official Slack documentation. e.g if you look at [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) you can see that there is no `text` property, but there is a comment property with a different name

Comment: Oh boy... yeah of course, I just looked it up. What an easy fix, it's called initial_comment. But come on... it is channel/channelS all over again... why do this? 
But yeah, I am trying to look into the documentation more, but it is hard for me to get a clue out of the most parts. This made sense to me now. Since I learned how message properties work here. But in the beginning this was like looking at hiroglyphs.

Thank you very much, again! :)