# Why do I get "invalid_form_data" error when trying to post to Slack-API?

Tags: c#, json, slack-api

When I use this method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileAsync(MultipartFormDataContent requestContent)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, UriMethod);
    request.Content = requestContent;
    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

    return response;
}
```

I allways get the answer:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_form_data"}
```

so I tried to explicitly tell it the 'mediaType', I tried "application/json" and others, but with all of them I get the same error. Here is the full Main-method that calls the upper method:

```
    namespace TestArea
    {
        class MainArea
        {
            public static void Main( string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    Task.WaitAll(SendMessage());
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }

 private static async Task SendMessage()
    {
        var client = new BpsHttpClient("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");
        JsonObject JO = new JsonObject();
        JO.channel = "DCW21NBHD";
        JO.text = "This is so much fun :D !";
        var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JO, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

        var StringJson = new StringContent(Json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        requestContent.Add(StringJson);

        var Response = await client.UploadFileAsync(requestContent);

        string AnswerContent = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    }
```

When I use this method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessageAsync(FormUrlEncodedContent content)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(UriMethod, content);

    return response;
}
```

so basically I am passing "FormUrlEncodedContent" instead of "MultipartFormDataContent" in this, and then I get the response I want and can work wiht it. BUT this is of little use to me since I have to use "MultipartFormDataContent" to be able to send files with my requests.

Anyone have an idea what is failing here? Why does it not like the one content-type but the other one? I'd be gratefull for tipps and ideas!

Comment: Havent worked with slack api, but i wonder if you shouldnt set the request you create as multipart also un your UploadFileAsync function

Comment: What is the point of using `JsonConvert` with `JsonObject` ? Do you know what is debugging? did you AT LEAST LOG `var Json`?

Comment: @FrancoPettigrosso - there is no foul language anyhwere...
@Selvin - very helpfull, thanks for nothing.
@bradbury9 - To be honest I can't say, I've been using this method in an older version of this code just fine. But in the older version I do not serialize into Json with Newtonsoft's NuGet-package but instead used `Dictionary<string,string>` to serialize my objects... any other ideas? I mean it obviously has to do with my JSonObjects...

Comment: @FabianHeld in your main method in the class MainArea, you have 'ass'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error "invalid_form_data", because the API method `chat.postMessage` does not support requests with `multipart/form-data`.

As you can see from the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) under "Accepted content types" this method only accepts: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `application/json`

Note that you can not upload files to `chat.postMessage`.

If you want to upload files, please use the API method [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload), which also supports `multipart/form-data`.

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53338803/4379151) for how to upload files with a comment.

Comment: Hey Erik, I know which methods I can use for what. You of all people should know :) I did not try to upload anything, I simply wanted to post a message. I just HAVE TO BE ABLE to use the other methods, too. And be able upload files. But now I just want to post a message - you know, start with the simplest method. And as I wrote, I tried all three content types ALL THREE!!! That is what makes me so mad... it doesn't make a difference. I allways get the same error.

Comment: Interesting enough, when I do NOT put my serialized `JsonObject` into a 'MultipartFormData' but instead send the JsonObject directly - which also should work, since I only need 'Multipart' to be able to add a file later on - I get the error "not_authed". So, this tells me my JsonObject is f***ed somehow. But when I deserialize my JsonObject it looks totally fine...

Comment: It looks like this:
`{
  "as_user": true,
  "token": "xoxp-MyToken",
  "channel": "DCW21NBHD",
  "text": "This is so much fun :D !"
}`

Comment: When I create a Dicitionary<string,string> and create a "FormUrlEncodedContent" object with these parameters, it works flawlessly. But I want to use just my JsonObject-class, because it should work and it would make things a lot easier since I would'nt have to code every possible kind of message/request. So if anybody has a clue what's wrong with my JsonObject, I'd be very gratefull to hear it. :)

Comment: I just realized why you wrote that I shouldn't use MultipartFormData in chat.postMessage :D I'm an idiot. Yes, I used Multipart on this method... sorry. Okay then the real problem lies in the fact that my JsonObject somehow doesn't present the token correctly - like I wrote above. I get the "not_authed" error when I try it.

Comment: Yes. My answer is based on the code of your question. But happy to help with your next issue too of course.